# What is the best practices of doing row count with filter in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh

I have inserted the data from flume to HBase. and I want to check data consistency.

I mean HBase provided command "count", which provided total rows of a table.

The problem is "Count" cannot be used with "Filter"

Is there some way to do row-counting with some specific conditions such as Filter?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column that you are going to filter is part of the row key then set **start and stop row keys** or you can use **fuzzy filter** so that we could avoid a Full table scan and just we could loop it around and get the count. Rather if we use any filters like SingleColumnValueFilter or something HBASE would go for a full table scan.